# Passenger doesn't seem to know the VirtualHost is a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I've configured Apache 2.2 with a VirtualHost for a Ruby on Rails (2.3.14) application.

However, when I visit the url for the website I'm presented with a directory listing.

I've checked that passenger (5.0.9) is loaded by Apache (it is) and I've got the loglevel set to 4 so I can see what passenger is doing. It starts up and indicates that it is listening for requests.

However, it would appear that passenger is not being invoked when the website is visited.

How does passenger know that it needs to handle this virtualhost?

Thanks

Comment: you need to load apache-passenger module in apache conf file

Comment: It is loaded - $ apachectl -M lists it

Comment: `LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8`
Something like this you are loading in apache config file.?

Comment: LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/passenger-5.0.9/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so

Comment: What about PassengerRoot..?

Comment: PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/passenger-5.0.9
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/wrappers/ruby

  PassengerLogLevel 4
  PassengerLogFile /var/log/httpd/passenger.log

Comment: There is a good chance you installed things in the wrong order. It's a common mistake. Try redoing the `passenger-install-apache2-module` again and see if it's fixed.

Comment: Just tried reinstalling Mike - still seeing the directory contents.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The rails application did not have a config.ru file.

After pinching one off the web for rails 2.3 the application now appears instead of the directory listing.

It appears from the passenger documentation this this file is used by rack to fire up instances of the application.